# Preparing storage for DRBD

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker, drbd

I am trying to set up high availability Linode server and using DBRD for data replication. I created primary partition using *fdisk*. But I get the error

> WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device
> or resource busy. The kernel still uses the old table. The new table
> will be used at the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or
> kpartx(8)

Thereafter, I rebooted and listed disk *fdisk /dev/sda* and partition was created.

But when I executed `sudo drbdadm create-md drbd0` it says Device or resource busy.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEJVX.png)

My question is how to actually prepare storage for DRBD? Do you use additional disk for DRBD purpose?

Comment: Are you sure that the partition is not automounted ? grep /dev/sda1 /proc/mount

Comment: Yes, the output of command says " grep: /proc/mount: No such file or directory ". Also, I didn't make any entry to fstab.

Comment: "No such file or directory" means grep or /proc/mounts was not found, not that it is not mounted. I do a typo : it is mounts (with a S) and not mount

Comment: Still no output to the command.